# How do I return a value of a Node type?

Tags: java, generics, types, nodes

I'm trying to complete the peek method using the Stack class. I'm trying to return the value of the top element.

```
public class stack<T> implements StackInt<T>
{
     Node<T> root;     
     public boolean isEmpty()
     {   
         Node<T> top = root;
         if( top == null)
         {
            return true;
         }
         return false;
     }

public T peek() throws EmptyStackException
     {
         Node<T> top = root;
         if(isEmpty())
         {
            throw new EmptyStackException("stack underflow");
         }
         return top.val;
     }
}
```

When I compile it gives me an error:

```
stack.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
         return top.val;
                   ^
  symbol:   variable val
  location: variable top of type Node<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class stack
```

Here is the Node class:

```
public class Node<T>
{
   T data;
   Node<T> next;

   public Node( T data, Node<T> next )
   {
      this.data = data;
      this.next = next;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return "" + this.data;
   }
}
```

What is the error in my syntax? I'm trying to use Nodes to create the peek/push/pop methods. But I have to use generic types which is T in my code.

Thank You

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you're trying to return a field that doesn't exist.

Comment: We would need to see the Node source code. Please see [mcve].

Comment: `Node<T>` doesn't have `val` member. How do you expect to access it?

Comment: How do I get the value of that node then? Can I cast as T and return top?

Comment: By *value of that node* you mean the `data` member?

Comment: Yes, as in if I were to return top it would return the memory location correct? How am I able to return whats in the node, is that the data member?

Comment: You don't appear to understand your own code. `data` is the only field in `Node<T>` of type T. Hard to see what else you should be returning, or where you got `top.val` from.

Answer (score 1):

Make `data` and `next` private and add a getters

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "" + this.data;
    }
}
```

Uses: `top.getData();`

Comment: Thank you, I completely misunderstood the structure of my classes. It makes sense what I did and what you did.